# Download solution to a new PC from TFS?

Tags: tfs

I'm playing with TFS in the cloud on http://tfs.visualstudio.com.  I have a new PC and want to download my solution to it.  I see how to connect to TFS from VS, and I can get as far as seeing my work items in VS, but I can't see my sourcecode.

I'll phrase this using Git or Mercurial terminology; how can I clone the repo to my new PC?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is done by entering the source control explorer. Here you'll have to set up a workspace to map the the folder structure to your local hard drive. Then you'll just need to "Get latest".

[A more detailed guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181384%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)